# Gradle app engine plugin not reflecting the changes made to .java files

Tags: java, gradle, google-app-engine, localhost

I have a spring application and I'm using app engine gradle plugin to run the run and deploy the application. I see that the frontend(jsp) changes are getting reflected even without having to restart the server. But the java class changes are not reflected even after restarting and deleting the build folder. What could be an issue? This is my build.gradle file

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.4.4'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine-appenginewebxml'

ext.getAppVersion = { ->
    return project.property('version')
}

appengine {
    tools {
        cloudSdkVersion = '449.0.0'
    }
    run {
        // ./gradlew appengineStart (to run the app locally)
        // ./gradlew appengineStop
        jvmFlags = ["-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5"]
        projectId= 'xxxx'
        services = '../war'
        port = 8080
        automaticRestart = true
    }
}

//  ./gradlew deploy -Pversion=version_name
task deploy {
    doLast {
        def versionName = getAppVersion()
        exec {
            commandLine 'gcloud', 'app', 'deploy', '--quiet', '../war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml', '--version=' + versionName, '--no-promote'
        }
    }
}

explodeWar {
    with copySpec {
        from '../war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF'
    }
}
```

Even tried the debug mode as mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md#how-do-i-debug-dev-appserver-v1) , but no luck

Comment: Based on this documentation on [using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle), Gradle version should be `3.4.1` or newer. Please check with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following configuration using Gradle for App Engine plugin:

- [Using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin (standard)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle)
- [Using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin (flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-gradle)

The `build.gradle` file should look like this:

```
buildscript {      // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()      // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.5.0'
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

dependencies {
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
// Add your dependencies here.

}

gretty {
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'  // What App Engine Flexible uses
}

  appengine {
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
      stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
      promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }
  }

group = 'com.example.appengine'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Follow the steps carefully depending on your App Engine environment (standard or flexible).

If the aforementioned steps didn't work, you may file an issue through their [Github for GAE Gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin).